# ¿Cómo puedo mejorar el tiempo de ejecución de mi consulta en mysql, si estoy comparando valores que vienen de join?

Tags: mysql

La consulta es la siguiente:

```sql
select 
`productoservicios`.`id`, 
`productoservicios`.`clave`, 
`productoservicios`.`codigobarras`, 
`productoservicios`.`nombre`, 
`productoservicios`.`marca`, 
`unidades`.`clave` as `unidadesclave`, 
`productoservicios`.`preciocompra`, 
`productoservicios`.`porcentajebeneficio`, 
`productoservicios`.`precioventa`, 
`cc1alm1`.`cantidad` as `cc1alm1cantidad`, 
`cc1alm2`.`cantidad` as `cc1alm2cantidad`, 
`cc1alm3`.`cantidad` as `cc1alm3cantidad`, 
`cc2alm4`.`cantidad` as `cc2alm4cantidad`, 
`cc2alm5`.`cantidad` as `cc2alm5cantidad`
from `productoservicios` 
left join `inventarios` as `cc1alm1` on `cc1alm1`.`productoservicio_id` = `productoservicios`.`id` and `cc1alm1`.`almacene_id` = 1 
left join `inventarios` as `cc1alm2` on `cc1alm2`.`productoservicio_id` = `productoservicios`.`id` and `cc1alm2`.`almacene_id` = 2 
left join `inventarios` as `cc1alm3` on `cc1alm3`.`productoservicio_id` = `productoservicios`.`id` and `cc1alm3`.`almacene_id` = 3 
left join `inventarios` as `cc2alm4` on `cc2alm4`.`productoservicio_id` = `productoservicios`.`id` and `cc2alm4`.`almacene_id` = 4 
left join `inventarios` as `cc2alm5` on `cc2alm5`.`productoservicio_id` = `productoservicios`.`id` and `cc2alm5`.`almacene_id` = 5 
inner join `unidades` on `productoservicios`.`unidade_id` = `unidades`.`id` 
where 
`cc1alm1`.`cantidad` <> 0 
or `cc1alm2`.`cantidad` <> 0 
or `cc1alm3`.`cantidad` <> 0 
or `cc2alm4`.`cantidad` <> 0
or `cc2alm5`.`cantidad` <> 0 
limit 25 offset 0
```

Mientras no agrego la sección de la consulta

```sql
where 
`cc1alm1`.`cantidad` <> 0 
or `cc1alm2`.`cantidad` <> 0 
or `cc1alm3`.`cantidad` <> 0 
or `cc2alm4`.`cantidad` <> 0
or `cc2alm5`.`cantidad` <> 0
```

Todo corre perfectamente (al menos en el servidor de producción, localmente es fatal, aún con un Nmve, pero localmente puedo modificar el time out de mysql), después de eso el servidor termina la consulta por tiempo de espera.

La consulta me regresa las existencias en almacenes como columnas, en éste caso mientras una de las columnas no tenga ceros, y funciona localmente, pero se cuelga en el servidor.

He intentado de todo.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Creo que sería ideal que agregues a tu pregunta información básica sobre las tablas, como la cantidad de registros que hay en cada una, índices, etc. Sería genial que también incluyas el plan de ejecución que tu servidor está usando para la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Existen diversas maneras en las que puedes optimizar tu consulta SQL. Aquí hay algunos consejos:

1. **Indices**: Asegúrate de que las columnas utilizadas en las cláusulas JOIN y WHERE estén indexadas. La creación de índices en estas columnas puede mejorar significativamente la velocidad de las consultas. En tu caso, deberías tener índices en `productoservicio_id`, `almacene_id` y `cantidad` en la tabla `inventarios`.
2. **Reorganizar la consulta**: Puedes intentar reorganizar tu consulta para minimizar el número de tablas en la operación JOIN. Esto puede hacer que la consulta sea más eficiente.
3. **Usar JOINs en lugar de subconsultas**: Si estás usando subconsultas en tu consulta original, intenta convertirlas en JOINs ya que son generalmente más rápidos.
4. **Usar EXPLAIN PLAN**: MySQL tiene una herramienta muy útil llamada EXPLAIN que puedes usar para entender cómo el motor de base de datos está ejecutando tu consulta. Esto puede proporcionarte información valiosa sobre dónde están los cuellos de botella y cómo podrías reescribir tu consulta para que sea más eficiente.
5. **Filtrado temprano**: Intenta mover las condiciones de filtrado (`WHERE`) lo más pronto posible en tu consulta para limitar el número de filas con las que MySQL tiene que trabajar.
6. **Evitar consultas completas de tabla**: Las consultas completas de tabla pueden ser costosas en términos de rendimiento. Si es posible, intenta limitar la cantidad de datos que tu consulta tiene que leer.

Espero que estos consejos te ayuden a optimizar tu consulta. Recuerda, la optimización de consultas puede ser un proceso de prueba y error, y lo que funciona en un escenario puede no funcionar en otro. Si aún sigues teniendo problemas, no dudes en pedir más ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo implementaré. De hecho la consulta va a crecer, así que no puedo limitar los join. Crece puesto que todos los campos con alias de número en los join se agregan dinámicamente (con eloquent en laravel) según la cantidad de almacenes y centros de costo, así que será en el mejor de los casos mucho más pesada.

Comment: Si estás usando una implementación de GPT, **que no se note**. Además, debías editar tu respuesta para agregar más detalles, no formular otra.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus observaciones, como puedes ver soy un usuario nuevo y la herramienta o referencias que utilice mientras sean de ayuda las seguire usando, implementare lo que me mencionas.

Comment: [Política temporal: CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462).

Comment: Lo tomare en cuenta, muchas gracias no tenia conocimiento de la politica <(＿　＿)>

Answer (score 0):

He reorganizado un poco tu consulta y agregado algunos comentarios para ayudarte a entender las sugerencias que mencioné:

```sql
SELECT 
    productoservicios.id, 
    productoservicios.clave, 
    productoservicios.codigobarras, 
    productoservicios.nombre, 
    productoservicios.marca, 
    unidades.clave as unidadesclave, 
    productoservicios.preciocompra, 
    productoservicios.porcentajebeneficio, 
    productoservicios.precioventa, 
    cc1alm1.cantidad as cc1alm1cantidad, 
    cc1alm2.cantidad as cc1alm2cantidad, 
    cc1alm3.cantidad as cc1alm3cantidad, 
    cc2alm4.cantidad as cc2alm4cantidad, 
    cc2alm5.cantidad as cc2alm5cantidad 
FROM productoservicios 
INNER JOIN unidades 
    ON productoservicios.unidade_id = unidades.id 
LEFT JOIN inventarios as cc1alm1 
    ON cc1alm1.productoservicio_id = productoservicios.id 
    AND cc1alm1.almacene_id = 1 
LEFT JOIN inventarios as cc1alm2 
    ON cc1alm2.productoservicio_id = productoservicios.id 
    AND cc1alm2.almacene_id = 2 
LEFT JOIN inventarios as cc1alm3 
    ON cc1alm3.productoservicio_id = productoservicios.id 
    AND cc1alm3.almacene_id = 3 
LEFT JOIN inventarios as cc2alm4 
    ON cc2alm4.productoservicio_id = productoservicios.id 
    AND cc2alm4.almacene_id = 4 
LEFT JOIN inventarios as cc2alm5 
    ON cc2alm5.productoservicio_id = productoservicios.id 
    AND cc2alm5.almacene_id = 5 
WHERE (cc1alm1.cantidad <> 0 OR cc1alm2.cantidad <> 0 OR cc1alm3.cantidad <> 0 OR cc2alm4.cantidad <> 0 OR cc2alm5.cantidad <> 0)
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

El primer paso sería utilizar la herramienta `EXPLAIN` para entender cómo MySQL está ejecutando la consulta:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT 
... (el resto de tu consulta)
```

Esto te dará una tabla de resultados que describe los pasos que MySQL toma para ejecutar la consulta, y te ayudará a entender dónde se producen los cuellos de botella.

Como siguiente paso, asegúrate de tener índices en las columnas `productoservicio_id`, `almacene_id` y `cantidad` en la tabla `inventarios`. Esto se puede hacer con consultas similares a:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_productoservicio_id ON inventarios (productoservicio_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_almacene_id ON inventarios (almacene_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_cantidad ON inventarios (cantidad);
```

Por último, considera si hay maneras de reorganizar la consulta o los datos para que las operaciones de JOIN y WHERE se ejecuten sobre menos filas de datos. Esto es específico del conjunto de datos y puede implicar la creación de tablas intermedias, la realización de más filtrado temprano, o la reescritura de la consulta de diferentes maneras.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿En realidad era necesario publicar una segunda respuesta? Mientras es perfectamente válido hacerlo, esta no parece una respuesta distinta a la otra que publicaste, sino más bien una continuación de la misma, y por tanto, me parece que debiste editar la otra. Sugiero que lo hagas y elimines esta segunda respuesta. Haz el [tour] si no te queda claro por qué te lo pido. También puedes encontrar más información en [answer]. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Para qué el índice sobre cantidad? Agregar índices indiscriminadamente  se vuelve un problema.